# Does the Android emulator really support the GLES 2.0?

Tags: android, android-emulator, opengl-es-2.0, qemu

I can't understand how the android emulator behaves, sometimes it runs some applications that are using GLES 2.0 extensions and other times won't run anything and gives me several errors about a missing "EGL configuration".

http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2012/04/faster-emulator-with-better-hardware.html

here it is the announce for an emulator with full GLES 2 support, and here i publish a compiled sample from [this book](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Game-and-Graphics-Programming-for-iOS-and-Android-with-OpenGL-ES-2-0.productCd-1119975913,descCd-DOWNLOAD.html) which is one between many other app that won't run under an ARM emulator with ICS or JB.

http://www.sendspace.com/file/nl7aej

My question is not about this apk, i publish this apk just to give an idea, i would like to know what is wrong with the emulator itself and how i have to interpret the Google statements about this GLES support.

I also want to ask if using the flag

```
-gpu on
```

like this

```
emulator64-arm -avd avdName -gpu on -qemu -m 2047 &
```

with an avd that is not created with gpu emulation support, it's the same thing as creating a new avd with explicit gpu accelaration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem about the GLES 2.0 support with the emulator is that sometimes the EGL configuration and the emulation drivers are not so perfect, i found the GLES configuration on the X86 Ice Cream Sandwich image from Intel very disappointing for example, and worst if compared to the previous Gingerbread release for X86.

In the end i suggest to look for the EGL and driver configuration, but it can be a long road.

Answer (score 1):

I get the same error msg when starting while being positioned in an *.xml file. In these cases I just select a *.java file and everything works.

May be this also works in your case?

Comment: select what and how? can you explain this in detail?

Comment: being in the editor in an xml file vs in a java file - just doing the normal editing and from there pressing the debug/run icon

Answer (score 0):

The latest API (Android 4.1) does support GLES 2.0. If it doesnt run the desired apps you can try running them on BlueStacks. Have you considered that?